# Ubuntu does not start (fresh Installation on new computer - AMD Threadripper 3970X)

Tags: boot, uefi

I am working on a new set-up for my computer. My procedure for the new OS installation on a 250 GB SSD. First, I installed W10 using 200 GB with EFI and `secure boot` option activated in the bios. That works well on my machine. After that, I installed Ubuntu on the same SSD (50 GB). The installation worked well and also the GRUB2 works fine as I see both boot options, Ubuntu and Windows (I can still launch W10). However, Ubuntu freezes immediately after I select to start Ubuntu in the GRUB2 menu. After 1 - 2 s, also my keyboard freezes and I cannot do anything.

Therefore, I removed all partitions again and installed just Ubuntu. The installation procedure works fine here too but I select Ubuntu after the Grub2 menu appears, it freezes again.

I am using a TRX40 Pro 10G mainboard with the latest bios update. The only thing that I can analyze right now is the `dmsg` while starting the live usb stick. Here I get some data that I cannot interprete. Maybe they are not needed here but as I don't know what kind of information might be of interest to resolve this problem, I will add that information here:

```
[    0.020007] smpboot: CPU0: AMD Ryzen Threadripper 3970X 32-Core Processor (family: 0x17, model: 0x31, stepping: 0x0)
[    0.020007] Performance Events: Fam17h core perfctr, AMD PMU driver.
[    0.020007] ... version:                0
[    0.020007] ... bit width:              48
[    0.020007] ... generic registers:      6
[    0.020007] ... value mask:             0000ffffffffffff
[    0.020007] ... max period:             00007fffffffffff
[    0.020007] ... fixed-purpose events:   0
[    0.020007] ... event mask:             000000000000003f
[    0.020007] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.020007] random: crng done (trusting CPU's manufacturer)
[    0.020007] NMI watchdog: Enabled. Permanently consumes one hw-PMU counter.
[    0.020007] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.020007] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[    0.020007] .... node  #0, CPUs:          #1
[    0.000000] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 0 at /build/linux-hwe-zHO4ZF/linux-hwe-5.0.0/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mce/core.c:1490 mcheck_cpu_init+0x1a7/0x4c0
[    0.000000] Modules linked in:
[    0.000000] CPU: 1 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/1 Not tainted 5.0.0-23-generic #24~18.04.1-Ubuntu
[    0.000000] Hardware name: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. MS-7C60/TRX40 PRO 10G (MS-7C60), BIOS 1.20 01/07/2020
[    0.000000] RIP: 0010:mcheck_cpu_init+0x1a7/0x4c0
[    0.000000] Code: 48 03 3d 44 30 1c 4f 45 31 c0 31 c9 ba 00 00 10 00 48 c7 c6 90 ba e4 b0 e8 26 3b 0d 00 e9 97 fe ff ff 39 d0 0f 84 e9 fe ff ff <0f> 0b e9 e2 fe ff ff c7 05 d8 c7 7e 01 89 01 00 00 e9 ff fe ff ff
[    0.000000] RSP: 0000:ffffb37b40207e90 EFLAGS: 00010002
[    0.000000] RAX: 000000000000001c RBX: ffff99da3ce4f040 RCX: 0000000000000179
[    0.000000] RDX: 0000000000000018 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: 0000000000000179
[    0.000000] RBP: ffffb37b40207ea8 R08: ffffb37b40207dd0 R09: ffffb37b40207dd4
[    0.000000] R10: 0000000000000c80 R11: ffff99ca7b7bcda8 R12: 0000000000000118
[    0.000000] R13: ffffffffb28fa060 R14: 0000000000000002 R15: 0000000000000000
[    0.000000] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff99da3ce40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[    0.000000] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[    0.000000] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 0000000ac360e000 CR4: 0000000000340ea0
[    0.000000] Call Trace:
[    0.000000]  ? detect_ht+0xf/0xd0
[    0.000000]  identify_cpu+0x3ea/0x580
[    0.000000]  identify_secondary_cpu+0x18/0x90
[    0.000000]  smp_store_cpu_info+0x49/0x60
[    0.000000]  start_secondary+0xa6/0x200
[    0.000000]  secondary_startup_64+0xa4/0xb0
[    0.000000] ---[ end trace 3ca88aad3131db8a ]---
[    0.020069]    #2   #3   #4
```

Additionally, I get errors for ACPI Errors. However, I think the problem is also not located here:

```
[    0.096076] ACPI: bus type PCI registered
[    0.096076] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[    0.096143] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-7f] at [mem 0xf0000000-0xf7ffffff] (base 0xf0000000)
[    0.096151] PCI: not using MMCONFIG
[    0.096151] PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
[    0.096151] PCI: Using configuration type 1 for extended access
[    0.097501] HugeTLB registered 1.00 GiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.097501] HugeTLB registered 2.00 MiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.100008] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
[    0.100008] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
[    0.100008] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    0.100008] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[    0.100008] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.100008] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    0.100008] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
[    0.117104] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.I2CA.WT1A], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.117110] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.117112] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Device (0x5B82)
[    0.117113] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.I2CA.MT1A], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.117116] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.117117] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Device (0x5B82)
[    0.117118] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.I2CA.WT2A], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.117120] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.117122] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Device (0x5B82)
[    0.117123] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.I2CA.MT2A], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.117125] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.117126] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Device (0x5B82)
[    0.117127] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.I2CA.WT3A], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.117129] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.117130] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Device (0x5B82)
[    0.117131] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.I2CA.MT3A], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.117133] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.117135] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Device (0x5B82)
[    0.117136] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.I2CA.WT4A], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.117138] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.117140] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Device (0x5B82)
[    0.117141] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.I2CA.MT4A], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.117143] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.117145] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Device (0x5B82)
[    0.117146] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.I2CA.MT5A], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.117148] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.117150] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Device (0x5B82)
[    0.117152] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.I2CB.WT1B], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.117155] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.117156] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Device (0x5B82)
[    0.117157] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.I2CB.MT1B], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.117160] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.117161] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Device (0x5B82)
[    0.117162] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.I2CB.WT2B], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.117165] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.117166] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Device (0x5B82)
[    0.117167] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.I2CB.MT2B], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.117170] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.117171] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Device (0x5B82)
```

Any hint is welcomed. 
I also add missing information (I guess there are a lot missing here). Please note, starting from recovery mode freezes the system too.

Comment: Hey everybody, I will check this out later on. https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-Boot-Threadripper-Zen2MCE

Comment: Are you using a boot disk EX: USB or CD or an installed disk EX: Hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was actually the problem given in the link I set in my first comment (https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-Boot-Threadripper-Zen2MCE). For those who are not too familiar with it, I will give a brief description here. If you do have booting problems with the latest threadripper CPU's, you need to do the following:

- Install Ubuntu as you do usually
- If boot instantly freezes always, boot your system with the Live USB stick
- After you are in the Live system, mount the device where you installed your OS, e.g.,

  ```
  mkdir temporaryMount
  sudo mount /dev/yourDevice temporaryMount
  ```
- After that you open your `grub.cfg` file

  ```
  sudo gedit temporaryMount/boot/grub/grub.cfg
  ```
- If you are not sure where your `grub.cfg` file is located, you can search for it

  ```
  find -iname grub.cfg
  ```
- After that you have to insert the `mce=off` keyword to your boot line (please see the link at the beginning)

This did the trick for me. Hope it will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

You have UEFI/EFI BIOS in your machine ?

Then try at begin of booting to press key 'F2' or 'F12'
for to get into setup of BIOS. Then goto section "Boot" in BIOS.

In the settings for "Boot" you can switch UEFI to "Legacy" mode.

When "Legacy" mode is active - after leaving BIOS with saving the setup - you should be able to install Ubuntu with success.

Topic BIOS is off-topic here, but this is necessary for to install
Ubuntu (or other distros) then.

Comment: Hi, not sure why you think I cannot install Ubuntu. As I said, I can install Ubuntu without any problem but while booting the OS, the system freezes. This is related to the CPU. I do have to add mce=off to the booting command.

Answer (score -1):

Was this fixed? I did mine the other night on my 3990x, it froze and I couldn't get around it, so where I put in `mce=off`, I took out the `quiet splash` and replaced it with `nomodeset`. It booted fine thereafter and so I made it a permanent edit in my grub:

Edit the file `/etc/default/grub`, for example run

```
sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

And between the double quotes after `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` add `nomodeset`, so the line reads

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
```

Save the file and exit, and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

I mean, it'll load every time with the code running down the screen but that's the only downside...

Comment: you can add back the `quiet splash` along with `nomodeset` (they are not incompatible) and you will not see the boot messages any more (in theory)

Comment: Cool! Thanks Zanna. 